# Notation for string modes in open string Hamiltonian

Tags: string-theory, notation

I'm learning string theory from Becker, Becker & Schwarzs textbook. I'm having some trouble with some notation that isn't clearly explained:

In chapter 2, *The Bosonic String* in the section titled *Open string mode expansion*, they give the general solution of the equation of motion for an open string as a series over exponential terms which represent the string excitation modes; and they introduce the string modes

> $\alpha^{\mu}_n$

as the coefficient of these exponential terms.

In the next section on *The Hamiltonian and energy-momentum tensor* they use the following

> $\alpha_n$

in giving the formula for the open string Hamiltonian. The superscript $\mu$ is missing. t's not explained how this is related to the above. Is it as simple as saying this is just the $\mu=0$ component?

Comment: Sometimes the $\mu$ index is omitted if not pertinent. Furthermore, notation like $\alpha_m \cdot \alpha_n$ may omit the index, to mean $\alpha^\mu_m \alpha_{\mu n}$, i.e. an inner product.

Comment: @JamalS: Sure, it's useful when a notation is a bit heavy on indexes; but in a pedagogical context, like a textbook that sort of thing is usually explained.

Comment: @JamalS: it looks like it's the second notational convenience that's been used here. Thanks.